# Docker database does not exist

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I am developing using docker in a Django project. For this project I need multiple PostgreSQL database live at the same time to work. So, I put in the env file all the current settings:

```
DB_ENGINE="django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2"
POSTGRES_USER="zwap_user_settings_db"
POSTGRES_DB="zwap_user_settings_db"
DB_HOST="zwap_user_settings_postgres"
DB_PORT="5432"
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=zwap_settings_postgres_db
```

And I created the docker-compose.yml file to create all the needed postgresql instance at once

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  ...
      
  zwap_settings_postgres:
    container_name: zwap_user_settings_postgres
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 6003:5432/tcp
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=zwap_user_settings_db
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=zwap_settings_postgres_db
      - POSTGRES_DB=zwap_user_settings_db
    volumes:
      - zwap_settings_postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  ...
      
volumes:
  ...
  zwap_settings_postgres:
```

So, I try to run the Django project and this error occurs:
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "zwap_user_settings_db" does not exist`  and this error appears also in the docker terminal. But I don't understand where is the error. The code is the same everywhere. Maybe it is simply a silly thing that needs to be changes. IF someone knows how to fix, please help me. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I've tried the `docker-compose.yml` template for myself too like below:

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  zwap_settings_postgres:
    container_name: zwap_user_settings_postgres
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 6003:5432/tcp
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=zwap_user_settings_db
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=zwap_settings_postgres_db
      - POSTGRES_DB=zwap_user_settings_db
    volumes:
      - zwap_settings_postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

volumes:
  zwap_settings_postgres:
    driver: local
```

Then, after `docker-compose up -d` it produced the container with following details below:
[image]

Then, I tested the connection to `postgres` container with JetBrains DataGrip and connection was successful - and yes, the schema name `zwap_user_settings_db` was present. See screenshot below as described:
[image]

Lastly, based on the connection test, I reckon the following `.env` fields needs correction, as suggested below:

```
DB_ENGINE="django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2"
POSTGRES_USER="zwap_user_settings_db"
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=zwap_settings_postgres_db
POSTGRES_DB="zwap_user_settings_db"
DB_HOST="localhost"
DB_PORT="6003"
```

Hope the suggested correction for `DB_HOST` and `DB_PORT` works!